# Got problem calling method from inherited aggregation

Tags: methods, aggregation, inherited

the following are my code. When I execute 'System.out.println(e.getBrowserInfo().getBrowser( )); ' in the last line of code in Webstat class. The result gives me 8 results of "Chrome". This is wrong as it is suppose to give answer as "Chrome" , "IE", "Chrome", "Firefox" ","Chrome","Safari","Chrome" & "IE". I have problem figuring out and please help on how to get the correct result.

---Code---------------------------------

```
package problem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import d1Assignment.Helper;

public class WebStat {
    private static int actionId = 100;
    private static String browser;
    private static double ConnectionSpeed;
    private String[] webinfo; 
    private  static ArrayList<SiteEntry> siteEntrydetails = new ArrayList<SiteEntry>();
    private static ArrayList<SiteExit> siteExitdetails = new ArrayList<SiteExit>();
    private static ArrayList<PageHop> pageHopdetails = new ArrayList<PageHop>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebStat wl = new WebStat();
        wl.start();
    }
    


    private void start() {
        
    
        int option = -1;

        while (option != 6) {
            updateArrayList();
            menu();
            option = Helper.readInt("Enter choice > ");
    
            if (option == 1) {
            //  AddNewSiteEntry();
            } else if (option == 2) {
            //  AddNewSiteExit();
            }else if (option == 3) {
            //  AddPageHop();
            } else if (option == 4) {
            //  ViewBrowseActions();
            } 
            else if (option == 6) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our Service!");
            }
          } 
        }
    private void menu() {
        
        Helper.line(60, "=");
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO MY WEB STAT PORTAL");
        Helper.line(60, "=");
        System.out.println("1. Add New Site Entry");
        System.out.println("2. Add New Site Exit");
        System.out.println("3. Add New Page Hop");
        System.out.println("4. List Browse Actions by Date Range");
        System.out.println("5. Export with Common Statistics Format");
        System.out.println("6. Quit");
    }
    private  void updateArrayList() {
        siteEntrydetails.clear();
        siteExitdetails.clear();
        pageHopdetails.clear();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("visitdetails.txt"))); //read file from items.txt
            String line = br.readLine();
            
                    while(line != null){
                        browser = "";
                        ConnectionSpeed = 0.00;
                        webinfo = line.split(",");
                        webinfo[0] = webinfo[0].trim();
                        actionId = Integer.parseInt(webinfo[0]);
                        
                        webinfo[1] = webinfo[1].trim();
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHH:mm");
                        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(webinfo[1], formatter);
                        
                        webinfo[6] = webinfo[6].trim();
                        double d = Double.parseDouble(webinfo[6]);
                        BrowseInfo browserInfo = new  BrowseInfo (webinfo[5],d);
                        //System.out.println(String.format("%-10d, %-10s, %-10s %-10s %-10s", actionId,dateTime,webinfo[2],browserInfo.getBrowser(),browserInfo.getconnectionSpeed()));
                        if(webinfo[2].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {//save entries with entry in visitdetails.txt into ArrayList
                            SiteEntry SiteEntryObj = new SiteEntry(actionId,dateTime,webinfo[3],webinfo[4],browserInfo); 
                            siteEntrydetails.add(SiteEntryObj);
                            
                            browser = "";
                            ConnectionSpeed = 0.00;
                        }
                        if(webinfo[2].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {//save entries with exit in visitdetails.txt into ArrayList
                            SiteExit SiteExitObj = new SiteExit(actionId,dateTime,webinfo[3],webinfo[4],browserInfo); 
                            siteExitdetails.add(SiteExitObj);
                            browser = "";
                            ConnectionSpeed = 0.00;
                            
                        }
                        if(webinfo[2].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("hop")) {//save entries with hop in visitdetails.txt into ArrayList
                            PageHop PageHopObj = new PageHop(actionId,dateTime,webinfo[3],webinfo[4],webinfo[5],d); 
                            pageHopdetails.add(PageHopObj);
                            browser = "";
                            ConnectionSpeed = 0.00;
                                                    }
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
            br.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();       
        }
        for(SiteEntry e: siteEntrydetails) {
            
            System.out.println(e.getBrowserInfo().getBrowser() ); //problem lies here
        }
    }
    
}
```

---Code End--------------------------------------------
--------Output--------------------------------

Chrome
Chrome
Chrome
Chrome
Chrome
Chrome
Chrome
Chrome

--------Output Ends--------------------------------

The below are contents of visitdetails.txt :

```
101 ,2021040903:07 ,entry ,www.google.com.sg ,home ,Chrome ,55.78
102 ,2021040914:43 ,entry ,www.google.com ,home ,IE ,99.11
103 ,2021040915:26 ,entry ,www.soccernet.com.sg ,home ,Chrome ,34.45
104 ,2021040915:41 ,entry ,www.google.com ,home ,Firefox ,233.00
105 ,2021040915:45 ,exit ,Join us ,www.google.com ,Chrome ,99.11
106 ,2021040917:37 ,exit ,Shop ,www.yahoo.new.com.sg ,Safari ,39.11
107 ,2021040917:43 ,hop ,Join ,Shopping ,Firefox ,88.11
108 ,2021040917:44 ,hop ,Check Out ,Join Us ,IE ,88.19
109 ,2021040918:03 ,entry ,www.google.com.sg ,Home ,Chrome ,88.11
110 ,2021040918:06 ,entry ,www.manutd.com ,home ,Safari ,99.11
111 ,2021041001:07 ,entry ,www.Liverpool.com ,Find ,Chrome ,89.11
112 ,2021041001:07 ,exit ,Shop ,www.mancity.com ,Firefox ,111.99
113 ,2021041013:57 ,entry ,www.google.com ,home ,IE ,71.77
114 ,2021041013:58 ,exit ,Check Out ,www.google.com ,Chrome ,38.19
115 ,2021041014:00 ,hop ,Join Us ,www.maskgowhere.com.sg ,Safari ,55.89
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to this. Can help to provide me on where to use markdown in Stackoverflow?

Comment: When you write any post either question or answer, you can format your question with markdown. Here is the link to learn about supported markdown in `stackoverflow` https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help